# Error 1 Invalid expression term 'double'

Tags: c#

```
        private void buttonConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Convert number from C to F
        double convertDecimal;
        convertDecimal = 1.8;
        textBoxF = double.Parse(textBoxC.Text) * double(convertDecimal) + 32;
                                                       ^here is where I get the error
```

Error 1 Invalid expression term 'double'

I am pretty new to programming and but I just can't wrap my mind around trying to add, subtract, dividing, or multiplying numbers. I am trying to do a simple a simple conversion. Take the number from the Celsius textbox and convert it to Fahrenheit. I just don't understand the number part???

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

double(convertDecimal) should be (double)convertDecimal

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a C++ type-casting expression, which doesn't work in C#. And as `convertDecimal` already is of type `double` there's no need to cast it. Just use it directly:

```
textBoxF = double.Parse(textBoxC.Text) * convertDecimal + 32;
```

You only need to change the type of a variable (i.e. type-cast) when the variable is of a type not expected. Adding two `double` values is okay. Even adding a `double` and an `int` is okay because the integer is [implicitly converted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) to a `double`.

---

**Edit:** You try to assign the result of the expression to a control, which will not work. You should convert the result to a string (e.g. with [`double.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hfd35ad.aspx)), and then assign to the controls text field:

```
double farenheit = double.Parse(textBoxC.Text) * convertDecimal + 32;
textBoxF.Text = farenheit.ToString();
```

Comment: Joachim, I do that then get this error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' "

Comment: @user2089370 That because you try to assign the resulting value (a `double`)  to a Windows control. You should convert the result of the expression to a string and set the text field of the control (i.e. `textBoxF.Text`).

Comment: @user2089370 Please see my modified answer.

Comment: Something like this? textBoxF = Convert.ToString(textBoxF);

Comment: Ok I feel stupid now. That makes perfect sense. Everytime I work with numbers in coding, I go blank and don't realize what's going on. Thank you so much for the explanation and help!